# angularJs ui-routing (basic)

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

1. I'm working for the first time with routing in AngularJs and I have a really hard time right now, Because I changed the documentation and first it worked and then it didn't. So what am I doing wrong? I am also using ui-routing for the app.
2. So now is my question. What is the best option on getting this to work.
3. http://embed.plnkr.co/QtM3ucPn6R1cPgdPjEzp/ this is my plnkr where I am making the routing app.

Answer (score 0):

[Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/ohcOkr3DHbIJdhbex87g?p=preview)

```
 angular.module('helloworld', ['ui.router'])
.config(['$stateProvider','$urlRouterProvider',function($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider){
    $stateProvider
    .state('home',{
        url : '/home',
        templateUrl : 'home.html'
    })

    .state('about',{
        url : '/about',
        templateUrl : 'about.html'
    })
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
}])
```

there were small mistakes in your code. you have used wrong syntax for config file. follow best practices. i have atteched working plunkr.. this is error free config. hope this will help you